# Is it not possible to export a database/catalog to a single file in HSQLDB

Tags: java, sql, database, hsqldb

I am in the process of refreshing/re-writing a data analysis application I wrote a couple of years back. What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

- I need to have a light-weight database to do queries to, I decided on using HSQLDB.
- I will have 2 applications; one for creating the DB and one that will do the analysis (will be used by others). It is my intention that the analysis software (which is multithreaded) will use the DB in a read-only fashion
- The DB will likely be distributed via FTP, and preferably with minimum hassle for the user of the analysis software (most of which are not very technically skilled).

I am not very well-read on SQL but I managed to get the info into tables and tried out simple queries. So in order to finish the "database creator" application I just need to figure out how to "package" the DB.

I have experimented both with *mem* and *file* "catalogs" [as described in the HSQLDB user guide](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_hsqldb_db) when I generate the DB. The way I see it, with *mem* catalogs I cannot write them to disk (to distribute later on) and with *file* catalogs I have several files that need to be taken care of:

> A file: catalog consists of between 2 to 6 files, all named the same
>   but with different extensions, located in the same directory. For
>   example, the database named "test" consists of the following files:
>
> • test.properties
>
> • test.script
>
> • test.log
>
> • test.data
>
> • test.backup
>
> • test.lobs
>
> The properties file contains a few settings about the database. The script file contains the definition of tables and other database objects, plus the data for non-cached tables. The log file contains
>   recent changes to the database. The data file contains the data for
>   cached tables and the backup file is a compressed backup of the last
>   known consistent state
>       of the data file. All these files are essential and should never be deleted. For some catalogs, the test.data and test.backup files
>   will not be present. In addition to those files, a HyperSQL database
>   may link to any formatted text files, such as CSV lists, anywhere on
>   the disk.

**Question(s):**

1. I think the `*.script` and `*.properties` files are the most important ones but the guide specifically says that all the files are essential and should not be deleted. Since there is no `*.data` file in my case, and all the data to generate my database is stored in `*.script` file (in clear text) it makes me think that when I "open" that file, the JVM recreates the entire DB all over again. Is this correct? Isn't this a very inefficient representation of data?
2. If my understanding in (1) is correct, why are the other files essential? Do I have to distribute them all?
3. If (1) and (2) are not off-track, then what options do I have to achieve my goal? Is it for instance feasible to gzip all the files and transport them that way? Then my analysis software would need to unpack them in a reasonable spot, and do a clean-up from time to time when it gets "crowded" in there...

Comment: You can use the `script` command: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#N1482D

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not sure I understand, the script command apparently creates a script that holds SQL statements to recreate the DB. Isn't that essentially the `.script` file that I already have? Page 3 of the user manual (HSQLDB) states: _"A res: catalog consists of the files for a small, read-only database that can be stored inside a Java resource such as a ZIP or JAR archive and distributed as part of a Java application program."_, that's what I was hoping to achieve

Answer (score 0):

1. If there is no *.data or *.lobs file then the .script file contains all the data as well as table definitions. In this case, the JVM recreates the database by reading the .script file.
2. The other files are essential if they exist. If you do not use LOBs, there will be no .lobs file. If you do not disk tables (CACHED tables), there will be no .data file.
3. You can distribute the .script file only. Each time this file is opened, a .properties file will be created if it does not exist.
4. You can use the res: option if your database does not change. For databases that change and need reloading use the file: option.